# Plot the decision surface of a classification decision tree with 3 features on a 2D plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, scikit-learn

My problem is that I have 3 features, but I only want to plot a 2D graphic while using 2 features at a time and show all the possible combinations.

The problem is that I did `classifier.fit(X_train, Y_train)` so it expects to be trained with 3 features, not just 2. `X_train` is the size (70, 3) which is (n_samples, n_features).

So far I tweaked the original code to add `z_min` and `z_max`, since I do need to have this third feature that I need to be able to use `classifier.predict()`.

The error I get at the `plt.contourf` instruction is `Input z must be a 2D array.`

```
import matplotlib as pl
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import matplotlib.cm as cmx

x_min, x_max = X_train[:, 0].min() - 1, X_train[:, 0].max() + 1
y_min, y_max = X_train[:, 1].min() - 1, X_train[:, 1].max() + 1
z_min, z_max = X_train[:, 2].min() - 1, X_train[:, 2].max() + 1

xx, yy, zz = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, 0.1),
                 np.arange(y_min, y_max, 0.1),
                 np.arange(z_min, z_max, 0.1))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# here "model" is your model's prediction (classification) function
Z = classifier.predict(np.c_[np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()], zz.ravel()])

# Put the result into a color plot
Z = Z.reshape(len(Z.shape), 2)
plt.contourf(xx, yy, Z, cmap=pl.cm.Paired)
plt.axis('off')

# Plot also the training points
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=Y, cmap=pl.cm.Paired)
```

`print(z.shape)` = `(4612640,)`

`print(xx.shape)` = `(20, 454, 508)`

How can I plot a 2D array + train with 3 features but only plot 2 features and keep the right shape for my array `Z` ? How can I get `Z` to the right size?

What I tried so far:

- [I read scikit-learn example with the iris dataset](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_iris.html)

I want something like this, bus instead I have 2 features and I can only predict 2 values, not 3 like the example.

- [Kaggle link 1](https://www.kaggle.com/elderbortolin/decision-boundaries-visualised-via-python-plotly)
- [Retrieve Decision Boundary Lines (x,y coordinate format) from SKlearn Decision Tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43929400/retrieve-decision-boundary-lines-x-y-coordinate-format-from-sklearn-decision-t)
- [plot decision boundary matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19054923/plot-decision-boundary-matplotlib)

But again all the examples I'm seeing, they are only training with 2 features so they are good to go from my understanding, they are not facing my problem with the `Z` shape that's not the right one.

Would it also be possible to visualize this with a 3D graphic so we can see  the 3 features ?

Comment: The problem is that you need to select only 2 features in order to create the 2-dimensional decision surface plot. this means that the fitting will be done using 2 features. This is the best way and gold standard way to go

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the shape/size is the main issue here. You have to do some calculation before you can plot a 2D decision surface (`contourf`) for a 3D feature space. A correct contour plot requires that you have a single defined value (`Z`) for each pair of `(X, Y)`. Take your example and look just `xx` and `yy`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': xx.ravel(),
                   'y': yy.ravel(),
                   'Class': Z.ravel()})
xy_summ = df.groupby(['x', 'y']).agg(lambda x: x.value_counts().to_dict())
xy_summ = (xy_summ.drop('Class', axis=1)
                  .reset_index()
                  .join(pd.DataFrame(list(xy_summ.Class)))
                  .fillna(0))
xy_summ[[0, 1, 2]] = xy_summ[[0, 1, 2]].astype(np.int)
xy_summ.head()
```

You would find out that for each pair of `xx` and `yy` you would get 2 or 3 possible classes, depending on what `zz` is there:

```
    xx  yy  0   1   2
0   3.3 1.0 25  15  39
1   3.3 1.1 25  15  39
2   3.3 1.2 25  15  39
3   3.3 1.3 25  15  39
4   3.3 1.4 25  15  39
```

Therefore, to make a 2D `contourf` work, you have to decide what Z you'd like to call from 2 or 3 possibilities. For example, you can have a weighted class call like:

```
xy_summ['weighed_class'] = (xy_summ[1] + 2 * xy_summ[2]) / xy_summ[[0, 1, 2]].sum(1)
```

This will then allow you to draw a successful 2D plot:

```
import itertools
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

iris = load_iris()
X = iris.data[:, 0:3]
Y = iris.target
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier().fit(X, Y)

plot_step = 0.1
a, b, c = np.hsplit(X, 3)
ar = np.arange(a.min()-1, a.max()+1, plot_step)
br = np.arange(b.min()-1, b.max()+1, plot_step)
cr = np.arange(c.min()-1, c.max()+1, plot_step)
aa, bb, cc = np.meshgrid(ar, br, cr)
Z = clf.predict(np.c_[aa.ravel(), bb.ravel(), cc.ravel()])
datasets = [[0, len(ar), aa],
            [1, len(br), bb],
            [2, len(cr), cc]]

for i, (xsets, ysets) in enumerate(itertools.combinations(datasets, 2)):
    xi, xl, xx = xsets
    yi, yl, yy = ysets
    df = pd.DataFrame({'x': xx.ravel(),
                       'y': yy.ravel(),
                       'Class': Z.ravel()})
    xy_summ = df.groupby(['x', 'y']).agg(lambda x: x.value_counts().to_dict())
    xy_summ = (xy_summ.drop('Class', axis=1)
                      .reset_index()
                      .join(pd.DataFrame(list(xy_summ.Class)))
                      .fillna(0))
    xy_summ['weighed_class'] = (xy_summ[1] + 2 * xy_summ[2]) / xy_summ[[0, 1, 2]].sum(1)
    xyz = (xy_summ.x.values.reshape(xl, yl),
           xy_summ.y.values.reshape(xl, yl),
           xy_summ.weighed_class.values.reshape(xl, yl))

    ax = plt.subplot(1, 3, i + 1)
    ax.contourf(*xyz, cmap=mpl.cm.Paired)
    ax.scatter(X[:, xi], X[:, yi], c=Y, cmap=mpl.cm.Paired, edgecolor='black')
    ax.set_xlabel(iris.feature_names[xi])
    ax.set_ylabel(iris.feature_names[yi])

plt.show()
```

[image]

If I understand this correctly, "visualize this with a 3D graph" will be difficult. You've got not only 3 features, which make it 3D, but also a class call. In the end, you actually have to work with a 4D data, or density like data in a 3D space. I guess this might be the reason why a 3D decision space (not really surface anymore) graph is not quite common.

Comment: Thanks! I had to change this line because it triggered an error. `xy_summ['weighed_class'] = (xy_summ.iloc[1] + 2 * xy_summ.iloc[2]) / xy_summ.iloc[[0, 1, 2]].sum(1)`. However I'm still wondering how did you come up with the weighted function? How do I know it's the correct one for my features?

Comment: @Mymozaaa I don't know. I made that up just to show you the concept/principle. I guess only you would know what the correct one is for your problem.